# JAXB and JFreeChart. It's possible?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jfreechart

I've readed about marshal and unmarshal complex objects and I would know if it's possible to use JAXB to create objects of JFreeChart API.

I've tryed myself but not works with the next code:

```html
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType( propOrder = { "id", "type", "renderer"})
public class Renderer {
            
  @XmlElement
  private Integer id;
  @XmlElement
  private Integer type;
  @XmlElement
  private XYItemRenderer renderer = new StandardXYItemRenderer();
        
  // Getter's / Setter's
  XYItemRenderer getRenderer() {
            return this.renderer;
  }



  public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer dataset_id) {
    this.id = dataset_id;
  }



  public Integer getType() {
  return this.type;
  }

  public void setType(Integer dataset_type) {
  this.type = dataset_type;
  }
}
```

It compiles, but when try to unmarshal the file, throws the next exception:

```css
WARNING [com.aws.chart]
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 14 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer is an interface and jaxb can't handle interfaces.
 this problem is related to the following location:
  at org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer
  at private org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer com.aws.chart.objectmodel.Renderer.renderer
  at com.aws.chart.objectmodel.Renderer
  at private com.aws.chart.objectmodel.Renderer com.aws.chart.objectmodel.Dataset.renderer
  at com.aws.chart.objectmodel.Dataset
  at private java.util.ArrayList com.aws.chart.objectmodel.Plot.datasets
  at com.aws.chart.objectmodel.Plot
  at private java.util.ArrayList com.aws.chart.objectmodel.Chart.plots
  at com.aws.chart.objectmodel.Chart
.................
```

I'm doing something wrong or simply it's not possible to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So it can be possible to do it, but it is not simple as that.

Firstly the JFReeChart classes that are referenced must be serializable by jaxb. As you cannot add anotations to them they must be marshallable/unmarshallabe using only defaults jaxb settings. With the complicated class chierarchy/object structure it may not be possible.

The issue with the interface or with not working default mapping may be solved by usied XMLAdaptor that will handle the conversion.

http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html

You will have to work with it by try and fix error approach to see what elements causes problem for jaxb. It may be too much work to solve them all.

Other approach will be using Java normal serialization, you could serialize the JFreeChart objects, and then encode the serialized stream in xml field as BASE64 for example. Then your class after unmarshling, could deserialized that field to re-create JFreeChart object.

So the esiest would be to have in your class

```
@XMLElement
String serialRender;

@XmlTransient
XYItemRenderer renderer;

boolean beforeMarshal(Marshaller mar) {
  serialRender = serializeToString(renderer);
}

void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unm, Object parent) {
  renderer = deserializeFromString(serialRender);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zielu for clarifiying this. I try the first approach because other packages of the application makes it with jaxb. If it is not manageable I'll try with the other approach. Any other suggestions would it be grateful.

Comment: Second approach was still with jaxb :) Just that it was mixed jaxb with java serialization to avoid jaxb problems outside your own code.